# UITableview indexPath.row returns wrong value in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to get an selected index path from uitableview.When i select 0,1,2 it returns the correct value but when i select 3rd row it returns the row index as 0(3rd row only displays only when i am scrolling).Please give me solution for that issue?
I am getting the table view id when user clicks the button which is inside uitableviewcell

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    UIButton *btnReadmor=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [btnReadmor addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(funReadmore:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnReadmor setTag:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)funReadmore:(id)sender
{


       UIButton *readMoreButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSLog(@"Select %d",[readMoreButton tag]);

}
```

**Here is the output:**

```
2014-03-15 10:58:43.765 BGrowB2B_28.1.14[3151:70b] Select 0
2014-03-15 10:58:46.701 BGrowB2B_28.1.14[3151:70b] Select 1
2014-03-15 10:58:48.693 BGrowB2B_28.1.14[3151:70b] Select 1
2014-03-15 10:58:52.013 BGrowB2B_28.1.14[3151:70b] Select 3
2014-03-15 10:58:53.668 BGrowB2B_28.1.14[3151:70b] Select 1
2014-03-15 10:58:55.476 BGrowB2B_28.1.14[3151:70b] Select 4
```

Comment: post some code so we can help you

Comment: are u Using section in tableView ?? if you are using Section then each section star from 0 to n number

Comment: Please give me some sample codes for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Check Whether you are using multiple sections in your table. If you are using two sections. You have to add previous section's rows count as well.

Example:

```
if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
    NSLog (@"Row :%d", indexPath.row + section0.count);

    [btnReadmor setTag:indexPath.row + section0.count];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can u explain briefly.Because i did not use section within uitableview.